# Candy box 2 hole in the ground

Tags: candy-box-2

When I fall into the hole it said I can move left and right by turning my device. That doesn't work how exactly do I do it.

Answer (score -2):

I am pretty sure that you're suppose to use the arrow keys on your keyboard...